# Cannot deserialize the current JSON

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms

[image]

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException   Message=Cannot
> deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Bmobile.Modules.Models.TrackOrderModel]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'data', line 1, position 8.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URL_Local + "order/presale/" + ProductOrderID);
string jsonData = "nul";
var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Bearer", Constants.Token);       
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TrackOrderModel>>(result)
```

This is my class file

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

public class Baddress
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object name { get; set; }
    public object line1 { get; set; }
    public string line2 { get; set; }
    public object line3 { get; set; }
    public string stateorprovince { get; set; }
    public int addresstypecode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
    public object postofficebox { get; set; }
}

public class Customers
{
    public string customerid { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public string emailaddress1 { get; set; }
    public string telephone1 { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string orderId { get; set; }
    public object orderName { get; set; }
    public string customerid { get; set; }
    public string billtoaddressid { get; set; }
    public string salesrepid { get; set; }
    public string shiptoaddressid { get; set; }
    public int customeridtype { get; set; }
    public DateTime datefulfilled { get; set; }
    public DateTime submitdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime pricingdate { get; set; }
    public object agent { get; set; }
    public object description { get; set; }
    public double discountamount { get; set; }
    public object transactioncurrencyid { get; set; }
    public double exchangerate { get; set; }
    public double discountamountbase { get; set; }
    public double discountpercentage { get; set; }
    public double freightamount { get; set; }
    public double freightamountbase { get; set; }
    public int freighttermscode { get; set; }
    public bool ispricelocked { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastbackofficesubmit { get; set; }
    public int opportunityid { get; set; }
    public int ordernumber { get; set; }
    public string billaddress { get; set; }
    public string shipaddress { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object billname { get; set; }
    public object shipname { get; set; }
    public string deliverynote { get; set; }
    public string shipnote { get; set; }
    public string termsconditions { get; set; }
    public string memo { get; set; }
    public double totalamount { get; set; }
    public object customername { get; set; }
    public Baddress baddress { get; set; }
    public Saddress saddress { get; set; }
    public string salesrep { get; set; }
    public double tax { get; set; }
    public double totallineitemamount { get; set; }
    public double taxperecentage { get; set; }
    public string totalamountinwords { get; set; }
    public string poreferencenum { get; set; }
    public string fulfillmentstatus { get; set; }
    public object notes { get; set; }
    public string picked { get; set; }
    public string packed { get; set; }
    public string quantitybackordered { get; set; }
    public string salesrepimage { get; set; }
    public string userimage { get; set; }
    public string confirmedbyname { get; set; }
    public DateTime confirmeddate { get; set; }
    public Customers customers { get; set; }
    public Shipments shipments { get; set; }
    public List<OrderProduct> orderProducts { get; set; }
    public object cancellationDate { get; set; }
    public string invoiceid { get; set; }
    public string paymenttypeid { get; set; }
    public string warehouseid { get; set; }
    public bool customeristaxable { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProduct
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string orderid { get; set; }
    public string productid { get; set; }
    public double baseamount { get; set; }
    public string transactioncurrencyid { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public string productimage { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public double priceperunit { get; set; }
    public double quantitypicked { get; set; }
    public double quantitypacked { get; set; }
    public double itemweight { get; set; }
    public double quantitybackordered { get; set; }
    public object picked { get; set; }
    public object packed { get; set; }
    public bool updatebackorders { get; set; }
    public object pickedbyname { get; set; }
    public object pickeddate { get; set; }
    public object packedbyname { get; set; }
    public object packeddate { get; set; }
    public object unitofmeasurementname { get; set; }
    public string upccode { get; set; }
    public object warehouseid { get; set; }
    public double onhand { get; set; }
    public bool itemistaxable { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public List<object> messages { get; set; }
    public bool succeeded { get; set; }
}

public class Saddress
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object name { get; set; }
    public object line1 { get; set; }
    public string line2 { get; set; }
    public object line3 { get; set; }
    public string stateorprovince { get; set; }
    public int addresstypecode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
    public object postofficebox { get; set; }
}

public class Shipments
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object shipmenttypeid { get; set; }
    public object warehouseid { get; set; }
    public string fulfillmentstatus { get; set; }
    public object routenum { get; set; }
    public object routedate { get; set; }
    public object truck { get; set; }
    public object driverid { get; set; }
    public object carrierid { get; set; }
    public object shippeddate { get; set; }
    public object trackingnumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime deliverydate { get; set; }
    public DateTime deliverytime { get; set; }
    public object deliveryagentid { get; set; }
    public string deliveryshipmenttypeid { get; set; }
    public object drivername { get; set; }
    public object carriername { get; set; }
    public object agentname { get; set; }
    public object agentimage { get; set; }
    public string deliveredusername { get; set; }
    public string delivereduserimage { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URL_Local + "order/presale/" + ProductOrderID);
string jsonData = "nul";
var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Bearer", Constants.Token);       
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TrackOrderModel>>(result);
```

i need answer, can any one , please help me

Comment: Error is  self explanatory...

Comment: You already got an answer. What is the question?

Comment: Please share the code you currently have and also the JSON you are trying to deserialize

Comment: after edit: This is not a code which is causing the problem ... there is no offended `TrackOrderModel` or rather its list ... which is not  a list/array in json as it's stated in error ...

Comment: it will be hard to explain as it seems like you do not understand english (error tells exactly what is the problem and also how to solve it)

Comment: in swagger, i have a post method, i pass the id in post methods, i have a success response, after JsonConvert.DeserializeObject , i have the Cannot deserialize the current JSON issue,

Comment: The json represents a single object, but you are trying to deserialize a **list of objects**

Comment: Don't deserialize to `List<T>` when json is not an json array. Also someone wrote the commented out code (prolly generator or some programmer) with usage and you didn't use it...

Answer (score 0):

the error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is and how to fix it

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object ... because the type
> requires a JSON array ... to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
> either change the JSON to a JSON array ... or change the deserialized
> type so that it is a normal .NET type

instead of this

```
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TrackOrderModel>>(result)
```

do this

```
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result)
```